# MongoDB performance issue with 3.6 version

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
 { "$and" : [ { "dataType" : "XYZ"} , { "dataVersion" : "VERSIONA"},
{"pub" : "true"} , { "obj.category" : "category1"} , {"obj.subCategory" 
:{"$all":["subcat1","sub-cat2","subcat3"]}}]}
```

Above query ran in 30ms in 3.4 after the mongo upgrade to 3.6 the same query taking more than 200ms . I have verified same on Compass explain as well it shows same amount of time for execution. I have recreated the indexes as well but nothing helped.
I have verified the index order too.

Comment: Could you add the explain output?

Comment: Query Performance Summary

Documents Returned:4818
Index Keys Examined:122548
Documents Examined:21883
Actual Query Execution Time (ms):311
Sorted in Memory:no
Query used the following index:
dataTypedataVersionstatuscategoriesObj.categorycategoriesObj.subCategory
FETCH
nReturned4818Execution Time
200
ms
DETAILS
IXSCAN
nReturned21883Execution Time
40
ms
Index Nameidx_dataType_dataVersion_status
Multi Key Indexyes
DETAILS

Comment: i have just modified one of the data here for sec reasons. pub equals to status on original data

Comment: The slow query log is useful, but I'd love to see the `explain` output -- it will show much more detail about what it's actually trying to do. `Documents Returned:4818 Index Keys Examined:122548 Documents Examined:21883` tells me that this isn't able to effectively use an index: it needs to fetch `21883` full documents to see whether they match the query, and need also needs to look at a whole bunch of different index keys.

Comment: Do i need to seperate the Comp index because previously it didnt use other index at all